# Eureka client can't reach Eureka server that's not on localhost

Tags: spring-boot, docker, netflix-eureka

I have two spring boot 3.1.5 docker containers, one for the Eureka server and another for the Eureka client.
Their configuration as follows:

Eureka server's:

```
eureka:
    client:
        fetch-registry: false
        register-with-eureka: false
    instance:
        hostname: eureka
```

The client's:

```
eureka:
    client:
        service-url:
            default-zone: ${EUREKA_URL}
    instance:
        prefer-ip-address: true
```

Given that the container for the server is eureka and `${EUREKA_URL}` is `http://eureka:8761/eureka` everything should work (according to the docs). However in the client logs I got the following:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hc.client5.http.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to http://localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: no further information
```

No matter what I put in the `service-url` or `hostname`, I keep getting `localhost`. I attempted to add `service-url` to the server side as well. Is there a way to change that behavior?